# Get incidents upper matrix

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, sparse-matrix

I have a matrix and each row/col have a number (as know as incident), for example:

```
    9  7  6
9 [[1, 2, 3],
7  [4, 5, 6],
6  [7, 8, 9]]
```

I want to get the upper matrix incident in two lists, one for rows and other for columns (because my matrix is symmetric). For example,

```
row = [9, 9, 9, 7, 7, 6]
col = [9, 7, 6, 7, 6, 6]
```

I can do this for the row with

```
import numpy as np

myIncidents = [9, 7, 6]
row = np.array(myIncidents).repeat(np.arange(len(myIncidents), 0, -1))  # [9, 9, 9, 7, 7, 6]
```

But I don't know how to achieve this for `col`. Any advice ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way with `masking` to get both `row` and `col` -

```
def triu_elements(a):
    n = len(a)
    r1 = np.broadcast_to(a,(n,n))
    r2 = np.broadcast_to(a[:,None],(n,n))
    mask = ~np.tri(n,k=-1,dtype=bool)
    return r2[mask],r1[mask]
```

Sample run -

```
In [56]: myIncidents = np.array([9,7,6])

In [57]: triu_elements(myIncidents)
Out[57]: (array([9, 9, 9, 7, 7, 6]), array([9, 7, 6, 7, 6, 6]))
```

**Timings : On various datasets**

Comparing @Paul Panzer's solutions with `np.triu_indices` here.

Set #1 (Small) :

```
In [105]: Incidents = np.random.randint(0,100,(100))

# @Paul Panzer's solution-1
In [106]: %%timeit
     ...: rowID,colID = np.triu_indices(len(Incidents))
     ...: row,col = Incidents[rowID],Incidents[colID]
10000 loops, best of 3: 66.8 µs per loop

# @Paul Panzer's solution-2
In [116]: %timeit np.fromiter(it.chain.from_iterable(it.combinations_with_replacement(Incidents,2)),int).reshape(2,-1,order="F")
1000 loops, best of 3: 259 µs per loop

In [107]: %timeit triu_elements(Incidents)
10000 loops, best of 3: 38.3 µs per loop
```

Set #2 (Large) :

```
In [99]: Incidents = np.random.randint(0,100,(1000))

In [100]: %%timeit
     ...: rowID,colID = np.triu_indices(len(Incidents))
     ...: row,col = Incidents[rowID],Incidents[colID]
100 loops, best of 3: 6.24 ms per loop

In [101]: %timeit triu_elements(Incidents)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.7 ms per loop
```

Set #3 (Very large) :

```
In [121]: Incidents = np.random.randint(0,100,(10000))

In [122]: %%timeit
     ...: rowID,colID = np.triu_indices(len(Incidents))
     ...: row,col = Incidents[rowID],Incidents[colID]
1 loop, best of 3: 1.08 s per loop

In [123]: %timeit triu_elements(Incidents)
1 loop, best of 3: 421 ms per loop
```

Comment: Yep, that's faster.

Comment: Actually, get the upper's (or lower's) incidents matrix, for me, it's the same. I need store a symmetric matrix. So with a `triu _elements(Incidents)` I got `99.3 µs ± 5.08 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)` while with a version `tril _elements(Incidents)` I got `87.6 µs ± 2.73 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)` (for `Incidents = np.random.randint(0, 100, (10000))`).

Comment: @rvcristiand I expected with `Incidents = np.random.randint(0, 100, (10000))` to have bigger runtime, not in `µs`. Could you check again?

Comment: @Divakar `555 ms ± 31 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)` and `431 ms ± 16 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)` respectively. At this moment I have many applications open.

Comment: @rvcristiand Appreciate the feedback. Makes sense now.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `triu_indices` and advanced indexing:

```
Incidents = np.array([9,7,6])
row,col = np.triu_indices(len(Incidents))
row,col = Incidents[row],Incidents[col]

row
# array([9, 9, 9, 7, 7, 6])
col
# array([9, 7, 6, 7, 6, 6])
```

For small to medium size arrays `itertools` are often faster than numpy:

```
import itertools as it
np.fromiter(it.chain.from_iterable(it.combinations_with_replacement([9,7,6],2)),int).reshape(2,-1,order="F")
# array([[9, 9, 9, 7, 7, 6],
#        [9, 7, 6, 7, 6, 6]])
```